# Tab not showing the data when changing user

Tags: lightning-web-components, user, lightning-tabset

I created a tabset with 3 tabs that hold the data of account, contact, lead, and I also created 2 users that both use Salesforce Platform user license.
It works perfectly fine as a system administrator but when I login to another user that I created, the tabset appeared but data won't come up.

I'm still learning and I appreciate any help you provide. Thanks in advance.

I'm remove the other 2 tab to make it shorter.

viewRecord.html:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Account Data" icon-name="channel_program_levels"> 

    <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
    <lightning-tab label="Accounts" onactive={handleAccountData}>
                <lightning-input placeholder="Search Account" onkeyup={handleAccountKeys}>
                </lightning-input><br/>  

                <div class="slds-scrollable--y" style="height: 15rem;">
                <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={accountRecords} columns={accountColumns}
                                    show-row-number-column hide-checkbox-column=”false”>
                </lightning-datatable><br>
                </div>
            </lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset><br/>

</lightning-card>
</template>
```

viewRecord.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import AccountData from '@salesforce/apex/AccountSoql.getAccountData';
    const getAccountColumns = [
    { label:'Account', fieldName:'AccountUrl', type:'url', 
    typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'Account' },}},
    { label:'Phone', fieldName:'Phone',type:'phone' },
    { label:'Industry', fieldName:'Industry' },
    { label:'Type',fieldName:'Type' }
]
export default class UserView extends LightningElement {
searchAcc = '';
    accountRecords;
    accountColumns = getAccountColumns;
    handleAccountKeys(c)
    {
        this.searchAcc = c.target.value;
        this.handleAccountData();
    }
    handleAccountData()
    {
        AccountData({'search':this.searchAcc}).then( res =>{
            if(res)
            {
                let final=[];
                res.forEach(row =>{
                    let fieldAssign = {};
                    fieldAssign.Id = row.Id;
                    fieldAssign.Account = row.Name;
                    fieldAssign.Phone = row.Phone;
                    fieldAssign.Industry = row.Industry;
                    fieldAssign.Type = row.Type;
                    fieldAssign.AccountUrl ='https://trailhead427-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/'+row.Id+'/view';
                    final.push(fieldAssign);
                })
                this.accountRecords = final;
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            this.error;
        })
    }
}
```

AccountSoql.apxc

```
public class CarAppDataSoql    
{
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccountData(String search)
    {   
        String item = '%'+search+'%';
        
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Industry, Type FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE: item];
    }  
}
```

viewRecord.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
        <target>lightning__UtilityBar</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Please read about [ask]. As written, there's no way we can help you. We'd need, at minimum, to see the code you've written, any errors you may have found in the developer console, etc. You can [edit] your question to add more information. We look forward to helping you as soon as you provide us with enough information to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I just finished editing.

Comment: Do the two Salesforce Platform users have access to the apex class?

Comment: I don't know, how can I check that?

Comment: Have a look at their profile and the permissions that come with them.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helps